# select multiple items with JS

Tags: javascript, selection

I have a bunch of divs (I'll call them items). Most have an image in them but having an image doesn't matter. How can I select these items, have the item show some way of being selected (I was thinking having padding which changes color?) and allow me to add more by hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and left click or by left clicking which creates some kind of mouse box and let me to draw a rect over the items I want to select.

I hope theres a JS container or lib that handles this, what can I use to do the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're OK using jQuery and its UI library I'd recommend using this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default